# Having Nikola ignore certain files

Tags: nikola

So basically all I want is to add data to my Nikola post folder (CSV, KML, ESRI Shapefiles, JSON, XML...),  my posts are written in Jupyter notebooks so naturally need to reference data for writing posts and I would like for those who view the blog to access to data to replicate the results (though I'm flexible on that point). For a while I was able to place extra folders and CSV files in the post folder without Nikola throwing a fuss that those are not a post. But now when I add new files to the posts folder and run *nikola build* it throws an error, so I may have either forgotten the method I used the first time or messed something up along the way.

Here's the error:

```
Scanning posts....[2017-12-16T01:18:56Z] ERROR: Nikola: Missing date in 
file posts/SnowGIS_SHP/README.txt
[2017-12-16T01:18:56Z] ERROR: scan_posts: Error reading post 
posts/SnowGIS_SHP/README.txt
[2017-12-16T01:18:56Z] ERROR: Nikola: Error reading timeline
[2017-12-16T01:18:56Z] ERROR: Nikola: Error loading tasks. An unhandled exception occurred.
[2017-12-16T01:18:56Z] ERROR: Nikola: ValueError: Missing date in file posts/SnowGIS_SHP/README.txt
[2017-12-16T01:18:56Z] NOTICE: Nikola: To see more details, run Nikola in debug mode (set environment variable NIKOLA_DEBUG=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm so silly, basically all I had to do was remove the README.txt file.

Comment: To clarify the dataset I was using had a README file, which I deleted, I did not delete my own README file.

Comment: Thanks @Sam.  I was linking in another library so that I could use it from a Jupyter Notebook (minecraft's mcpi in fact) and Nikola was tripping over their README.md and anything ending in .txt (like the spec, and the copyright license).  Renaming those fixed the Nikola post scanning.